# How to reference other inputs in the same "row"?

Tags: reactjs

```
onChange = ev => {
    // how to get all inputs in this row?
};

render = () =>
    <table className="MenuMenuOptionsWidget">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th className="id">ID</th>
            <th className="label">Label</th>
            <th className="order">Order</th>
            <th className="key">Key</th>
            <th className="active">Active</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {this.state.options.map((opt,i) => <tr key={i}>
            <td className="id">
                {opt.id ? [<input type="hidden" name={`options[${i}][id]`} defaultValue={opt.id}/>,opt.id] : '*' }
            </td>
            <td className="label">
                <input type="text" defaultValue={opt.label} name={`options[${i}][label]`} readOnly={!opt.active} onChange={this.onChange} />
            </td>
            <td className="order">
                <input type="text" className="number" defaultValue={opt.order} name={`options[${i}][order]`} readOnly={!opt.active} onChange={this.onChange}/>
            </td>
            <td className="key">
                <input type="text" defaultValue={opt.key} name={`options[${i}][key]`} readOnly={!opt.active} onChange={this.onChange}/>
            </td>
            <td className="active">
                {opt.id ? <input type="checkbox" value="1" defaultChecked={opt.active} name={`options[${i}][active]`} onChange={this.onChange} /> : <a href="#" className="cr-delete-link" onClick={ev => this.onClickDelete(ev,i)}/>}
            </td>
        </tr>)}
        </tbody>
    </table>;
```

I've got a "loop" in my render() function which renders a bunch of inputs. I want to add the *same* `onChange` event to each of them. How can I access all the inputs in the row that caused the change event if I do this?

I can access the input that caused the change event via `ev.target`, but how do I get the others?

I *could* use jQuery: `$(ev.target).closest('tr').find(...)` but I'm looking for the idiomatic React way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

you want to make use of the [`ref` property](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html). by adding a unique ref to either the tr and calling `children` or a unique ref to each td, you can grab them when you need them.

```
<tr key={i} ref={`row${i}`}>
```

then grab the ref using `refs`

```
this.refs.row1.children
```

will grab all the td's within row1

Comment: I didn't know if "dynamic" `refs` were appropriate or not. Can you do something like ``ref={`opt[${i}][label]`}`` instead to create  an object?

Comment: the name can be whatever you need it to be to properly identify the components you have. the information was just a bit ambiguous on how youre actually going to be using / identifying the other pieces, so i gave a generic example. the key take away is using refs is going to be your best bet at grabbing other child components. though at this point, you may want to extract each row out to a new component instead of having a giant one with a bunch of rows

Comment: Right, but if I use the square bracket syntax it won't become a dictionary like it would in PHP. I was hoping for an object to lump the inputs together; [Matt posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33832683/65387) a sol'n for that though.

Comment: if you put the ref on the tr and call children on that ref, it will be an array of all the td elements

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want the `td` elements, I want the `inputs`. And I don't want to search through a [Virtual] DOM tree to find the elements I'm looking for. That feels very jQuery-esque and brittle -- what if I want to change how the inputs are laid out?

Comment: in that case i would give each one of them a ref and then have a function that returns an array of all inputs like `[this.refs['input_1_row' + i], this.refs['input_2_row' + i] ...]`. at which point using jquery might be a better option

Answer (score 1):

You can use refs as a function. See [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).

Try something like this: https://jsbin.com/kixowo/edit?js,console,output

```
var Component = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
      return {
          options: [
              'Row 1',
              'Row 2'
          ]
      };
  },

  rows: [],

  onChange(row) {
      this.rows[row].forEach((input) => {
          // The values of all inputs in the row that changed
          console.log(input.getDOMNode().value);
      });
  },

  renderRows() {
      this.rows = [];
      return this.state.options.map((opt,i) => {
          // Store and cache a new row and store inputs in the
          // array using `refs` below.
          this.rows.push([]);
          return (<tr key={i}>
              <td>{opt}</td>
              <td>
                  <input ref={(input) => this.rows[i].push(input)} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, i)} />
              </td>
              <td>
                  <input ref={(input) => this.rows[i].push(input)} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, i)} />
              </td>
          </tr>);
      });
  },

  render() {
      return (
          <table>
              {this.renderRows()}
          </table>
      );
  }
});
```

This way you can build up a dynamic set of inputs and call your on change event with the row number as an argument.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/mnpenner/fc7eb5078fc2969bae87) seems to work. It's not weird to initialize inputs in a `.map` inside `render()` though, is it?

Comment: Nvm, that doesn't work. Complains about "Cannot set property label of undefined". Which is super confusing because I thought I initialized it.

Comment: I updated my crappy pseudo code which may assist with your problem. I will do a jsfiddle later when I get a free moment but.

Comment: Updated answer with a working example! Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think that'll work. You're pushing new rows everytime `renderRows` is called. Your example only works because it's only called once. If you have any calls to `setState` in there, this breaks.

Comment: True. Reset it on render before you push new rows `this.rows = [];`